# Gettting hand movements registered and sent to an arduino

Tags: arduino, kinect

I want to control a servo motor attached to an arduino through hand movements. I am just beginning the project and my idea is to attach a couple of accelorometers to each finger and then send that data to the arduino through Xbee . Firstly is this the right approach to doing this , or are there ready made sensors which I can wrap around my hand and send data to the arduino. Secondly I am stumped as to how to attach a Xbee sender to each accelerometer on my hand. Is this how its generally done? Does kinect even use accelerometers. Or is it some other kind of sensor. What would be the right approach to this project?

Comment: We need to know more about this gesture. Can you be quite specific, because this will, surprisingly, have a big impact on different implementations. For example do you need to know the X coordinate of the user's hand, or do you just need to know if the hand is roughly left or roughly right, or do you need to know that the user suddenly moved their hand to the left or right, or something else?

Comment: I just need to know if the user suddenly moved the hand to the left or right, up or down

Comment: In that case, you can strap an accelerometer to the user's hand, and just look at the amplitude of the acceleration. If it's high, then the user is making a sudden movement. The sign of the reading tells you if the movement is left or right.

Comment: yep. That sound like what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of questions embedded in there!  Let's try and unpack them:

1. The Kinect doesn't actually have **anything** connected to the user.  It functions by sending out a grid of infrared points and measuring how warped the grid is with a camera with an IR filter.  It has a lot of resolution for certain applications, but it doesn't work when the objects are very close to the Kinect, and it also can't measure anything which is occluded (i.e. if something is in the way you can't tell what happening behind it).
2. Getting finger and hand positions is very difficult.  You can slap an accelerometer onto each finger and put one on the palm, but interpreting what those accelerometer positions mean will be tricky to do in real-time.  On top of that, it'll be very expensive!  You can see some previous ideas in hand tracking with [the super colorful MIT glove](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rywang/handtracking/), here's someone [using the kinect](http://hacknmod.com/hack/kinect-finger-tracking-minority-report-esque-control/), and here's [tracking fingers with the wiimote](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0awjPUkBXOU).  Now note that all of these use a computer to back out the information from a sensor into hand positions, and you'll likely have to do something similar, unless you have more modest requirements for hand tracking.
3. Don't try and design the wireless component until you have a good method for getting hand positions.  A lot of the requirements for your hand tracking will change the requirements for the wireless: how often do you want to know hand positions?  How much detail do you need about the hand's position?  Once you know these, then you can go look and see what wireless solutions exist and implement something.  For example: if you did use 3-axis accelerometers (not saying it's a good idea, but if you did), one per finger, with a 10-bit ADC reading in the result from each finger: this gives 3 axis * 5 fingers * 10 bits = 150 bits per update.  That means that if you only used a single zigbee running at 115200 bits per second, you can have 768 updates per second (assuming no overhead, which is unrealistic).  But the point is that putting in 5 zigbees would be total overkill!  Just put in one radio.  And in a similar fashion, whatever solution you pick should be designed after you know what it needs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Right now my needs are only to sense the X axis movement. I was thinking of using Flex sensors instead of accelerometers since the aim is to only show that I can control the servo from my hand and interpreting data is much easier. With only an accelerometer on the X axis - do you think it will be easy to sense whether I move my hand to the right or left ?

Comment: Right or left relative to what?  Why not just put a lever on your device?  Do you need this to be contact free for a reason?  If you do, your best bet is probably to do something like the wiimote link I gave you and simply have the user hold an infrared led.  That will give you x and y position of a hand (or anything holding the IR beacon).  Alternatively just use a wiimote and have your project have a set of evenly spaced IR leds on the project.  There's a lot of libraries for getting data from a wiimote and they're cheap and will give you full positional information (x, y, z and orientation)

Comment: A gesture to the right would require the servo to rotate right and one to the left would cause it to rotate left. I want it to be contact free since I am experimenting with wireless communication using getsures.I dont need the x and y position. Only if the user has suddenly moved the hand to the right or the left